# Microsoft OAuth2 /token enpoint returns error code 900144 no matter what

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-identity-web

I'm trying to add OAuth2 ways to login to my app by following the instructions from [their official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). First step is to get the authorization code, I did it fine. However the next step doesn't work, it always gives me this error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: ff270385-1331-498d-94a1-bcedad81d100\r\nCorrelation ID: d7d7cdd3-2994-4a41-b8b0-7aebca34e81b\r\nTimestamp: 2023-04-22 23:04:06Z",
  "error_codes": [
    900144
  ],
  "timestamp": "2023-04-22 23:04:06Z",
  "trace_id": "ff270385-1331-498d-94a1-bcedad81d100",
  "correlation_id": "d7d7cdd3-2994-4a41-b8b0-7aebca34e81b",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"
}
```

It says it lacks the `grant_type` on the body, but the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) said to put those as query params. I put them on a body, same error. I remove everything from query strings and put it all on the body, same error. I put everything on both places, same error.

I looked around and found people telling to add an Content-Type header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, doesn't work either. More research and I found someone saying that adding another redirect URI with a trailing / on the Azure app did it for them, didn't do it for me.

At this point I just decided to mess around with the request and I discovered that no matter what I send, it always returns this error. I can give them no query strings, no body and that's the error I get. I send them fake code and ID, same error. My guess is that their error parsing is broken, if the request is wrong that's the error they return you.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still wondering whats the issue: ***The key is that you need to provide an encoded string to the body property*** not the url.

You create a `form` and pass it into the body as a string

```
 const uri: URL = new URL(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${YOUR_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`);

 const formData: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        formData.append("client_id", your-client-id);
        formData.append("code", code); // <- code from client consent
        formData.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        formData.append("scope", scopes.join("%20")); // <- "%20" is "space" encoded
        formData.append("redirect_uri", "your-return-url");


        const response = await fetch(uri.href, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            body: formData.toString()
        })


        const result = await response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application and added **Redirect URI** as below:

[image]

To get **authorization code** value, I used below authorization request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran the above request in browser, I got **`code`** successfully in address bar after signing in like this:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** using *Authorization code* flow via Postman by passing below parameters under **Body** section selecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: <code_from_above>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

> The error usually occurs when you pass these variables as **query
> parameters** while running the request to get access token.

When I passed those variables in **query parameters** under Params, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=appID&client_secret=secret&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&code=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, remove all variables under **Query Params** and pass them only under  **Body** section selecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Check whether **`Content-Type`** header is added or not like below:

```http
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

[image]